# How to combine tibbles with common but non-identical columns?

Tags: r, tibble

I have two tibbles, each with up to 4 columns. Each column name will either be common to both or missing from one or the other. I need to combine these into one tibble with two rows, and `NA` in columns where they are missing. I need to do this generically, so it works with more or less missing columns. Here's the code which produces the tibbles from two example web pages;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltab)

read_results <- function(filename) {
  doc <- read_file(filename)
  df <- as_tibble(htmltab(doc=doc, which="//table[@id='results']"))
  colnames(df) <- c("pos", "name", "time", "age_cat", "age_grade", "gender", "gender_pos", "note", "total_runs")
  tib = t(as_tibble(df) %>% group_by(substr(note,1,12)) %>% summarise(number=n()))

  colnames(tib) <- as.character(unlist(tib[1,]))
  tib = tib[-1,]
  r <- t(tib)
  return (r);
}

# saved from http://www.parkrun.org.uk/henleyonthames/results/weeklyresults/?runSeqNumber=2
r2 = read_results("results _ henleyonthames parkrun_2.html")
# saved from http://www.parkrun.org.uk/henleyonthames/results/weeklyresults/?runSeqNumber=4
r4 = read_results("results _ henleyonthames parkrun_4.html")
```

Now `t2` and `t4` contain

```
> r2
     First Timer! New PB! PB stays at  <NA>
[1,] "58"         "11"    " 3"         " 4"
> r4
     First Timer! New PB! PB stays at 
[1,] "62"         "16"    "11"
```

and I'd like to construct `t_all` to be

```
     First Timer! New PB! PB stays at  <NA>
     58           11        3           4
     62           16       11           0
```

Comment: How about `dplyr::bind_rows`?

Comment: @aosmith how do I match the columns by name with `bind_rows`?

Comment: My understanding of your question is that your tibbles share column names, and `bind_rows` works by matching on column names.

Comment: hmm, it works with dataframes, but not tibbles; `bind_rows(as.data.frame(r2), as.data.frame(r4))`. I don't know if that's a problem. I also get lots of warnings about coercing factors to characters. It's not a clean solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that one of the columns of r2 has a NA for name. Thus, most functions that pair matrix like objects on the basis of column names will fail. 
To solve it, add this line to your function: *names(tib)[is.na(names(tib))] <- "Blank"*

```
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltab)

read_results <- function(filename) {
  doc <- read_file(filename)
  df <- as_tibble(htmltab(doc=doc, which="//table[@id='results']"))
  colnames(df) <- c("pos", "name", "time", "age_cat", "age_grade", "gender", "gender_pos", "note", "total_runs")
  tib = t(as_tibble(df) %>% group_by(substr(note,1,12)) %>% summarise(number=n()))

  colnames(tib) <- as.character(unlist(tib[1,]))
  tib = tib[-1,]
  names(tib)[is.na(names(tib))] <- "Blank"  ## New Line
  r <- t(tib)
  return (r);
}

# saved from http://www.parkrun.org.uk/henleyonthames/results/weeklyresults/?runSeqNumber=2
r2 = read_results("results _ henleyonthames parkrun_2.html")
# saved from http://www.parkrun.org.uk/henleyonthames/results/weeklyresults/?runSeqNumber=4
r4 = read_results("results _ henleyonthames parkrun_4.html")

dplyr::bind_rows(as_data_frame(r2),as_data_frame(r4))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  `First Timer!` `New PB!` `PB stays at ` Blank
           <chr>     <chr>          <chr> <chr>
1             58        11              3     4
2             62        16             11  <NA>
```